# Content Security Policy - Determine source of blocked resource

Tags: firefox, web-config, content-security-policy

In Firefox I am getting the following error:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at data: (“media-src”).
```

I am unsure why I would get this error as I host no video or audio tags.

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
```

How can you find the source of the blocked resource in Firefox?

Any ideas why this would occur when the site has no external resources?

---

**SOLUTION**

I needed to include the `data:` attribute.

`media-src 'self' data:;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic ways to debug CSP:

1. Violation reports (`report-uri` directive) can give full info.
2. Chrome's console more informative than Firefoxes. Chrome shows blocked Url in console (Firefox - too in some cases).
3. The [SecurityPolicyViolationEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SecurityPolicyViolationEvent) provides the same info as violation reports (if you familiar with JavaScript).

Detailed info [how to debug CSP](https://csplite.com/csp30/).